# How to align a word below other which is on the right side

Tags: horizontal-alignment

As shown in the picture, I want the date to be below the external examiner. This is on the **right side** of the page. Help me
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have the impression, every one uses the `0.35\textwidth` style ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since nothing is specified, I used the `scrartcl` class and a table, with some
adjusting of a middle column width via `0.35\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}



\begin{document}

\bfseries%
\begin{tabular}{lp{0.35\textwidth}l}
Internal Examiner: & & External Examiner: \tabularnewline
Date: &  & Date: \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}%
\normalfont%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the columnwidth to whatever you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.35\textwidth} p{0.4\textwidth} @{}}
Internal Examiner: & External Examiner: \\
             Date: & Date:              
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `parcolumns` and `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}
        \begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true, colwidths={1=0.65\textwidth,2=0.35\textwidth}]{2}
            \raggedright
            \colchunk{ %
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    \textbf{Internal Examiner:}
                    \\
                    \textbf{Date:}
                \end{tabular}
            }
            \colchunk{ %
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    \textbf{External Examiner:}
                    \\
                    \textbf{Date:}
                \end{tabular}
            }
            \colplacechunks
        \end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularx`and  `setstretch` as the row spacing is too tight in tabulars:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pf]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}


{\setstretch{1.5}\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}lX>{\bfseries}rX@{}}
Internal Examiner: & & External Examiner: & \tabularnewline
Date: & & Date: & \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple plain TeX solution:

```
\settabs 2 \columns
\+ Internal Examiner: &  External Examiner:  \cr
\+ Date: &  Date: \cr    
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minipage`s too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
Internal Examiner:   \par\noindent
             Date:  
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
External Examiner:   \par\noindent
Date:
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variant in alignment will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\raggedleft
Internal Examiner:   \par\noindent
             Date:  
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
\raggedleft
External Examiner:   \par\noindent
Date:
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\bfseries\setstackgap{L}{1.5\baselineskip}
\Longstack[l]{Internal Examiner:\\Date}\hfil\hfil%
\Longstack[l]{External Examiner:\\Date:}\hfil}
%\par\noindent\hrulefill% This will show the margin extent
\end{document}
```